# MySql can't decide between LIKE and MATCH for text search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am building an application in Laravel. And I can't decide to go with `Match()` or `Like` for text searching.

I only want to do a text search on one column, that is a `Varchar(42)`.

I will also filter out the query by some `Where()` statements, so it will not do a text search on all rows.

I am using mysql 5.6+ so Match works with my innobd engine.

1. Does Match() do good in a table that has about 30k rows?
2. Laravel ORM doesnt support match so my query looks like this:

   ```
   $q = Input::get('query');
   Post::whereRaw("MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();
   ```

Do I need to sanitize the "$q" in order to be safe from SQL injections? Since I'm using `whereRaw()`

Comment: Yes the `whereRaw` is safe. The use of bindings (`?`) protects it from SQL injection. The rest of your question is covered in @GordonLinoff's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two capabilities are quite different, so the choice should be easy.  `MATCH` is focused on words within the text.  So, if you want to search by one or more words, then `MATCH` should be faster.  However, `MATCH` is focused on words, so searching on numbers, stop words, and short words requires extra effort.

`LIKE` generally cannot make use of an index.  This slows down such queries because every row needs to be processed.  Of course, if the rest of the filtering reduces this to 100 rows, then it is not a big deal.

Also, `LIKE` can use an index for "prefix" searches -- that is, searches at the beginning of the string.  So, `LIKE 'abc%'` can use an index.  `LIKE '%abc%' cannot.